# How do I list my HSED on my resume

Tags: resume, education

I have a HSED (high school equivalency diploma) which is slightly different from a GED. When I got my HSED 2 years ago, the instructor said it was closer to a high school diploma than a GED.

Should I list that I have a HSED or high school diploma on my resume?

Answer (score 9):

You're overthinking things, just list it as what it is:

> **EDUCATION**
>
> - 2017 HSED (High School Equivalency Diploma)